# Enabling/Disabling Shiro Security - Apache Camel

Tags: java, security, apache-camel, shiro, blueprint-osgi

i'm using Apache Camel route and i want to enable/disable Shiro security.

This is the route (blueprint.xml):

```
<bean id="shiroPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.component.shiro.security.ShiroSecurityPolicy">
     <argument value="shiro.ini"/>
 </bean>

<route>
<from uri="bean:com.ngt.secured.ShiroSecurity?method=tokeninject(Exchange)"/>
                <policy ref="shiroPolicy">
                        <to uri="bean:com.ngt.secured.transform?method=addrip(Exchange)"/>
                         ...
                         some process..
                </policy>
</route>
```

This is token injection (ShiroSecurity.java):

```
public void tokeninject(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
           {
           ShiroSecurityToken shiroSecurityToken = new ShiroSecurityToken(login,password);
           TestShiroSecurityTokenInjector shiroSecurityTokenInjector = new     TestShiroSecurityTokenInjector(shiroSecurityToken, passPhrase);
           shiroSecurityTokenInjector.process(exchange);
}
private static class TestShiroSecurityTokenInjector extends ShiroSecurityTokenInjector {
                   public TestShiroSecurityTokenInjector(ShiroSecurityToken shiroSecurityToken, byte[] bytes)
                   {
                        super(shiroSecurityToken, bytes);
                   }

                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("SHIRO_SECURITY_TOKEN", encrypt());
                        //exchange.getIn().setBody("Beatle Mania");
                    }
           }
```

in this case Security is enabled. How do I disable it ? is there an option to set On/Off ?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this while searching for a solution to a camel-shiro issue I have. Hope the response is not too late.

There is no option/property to set shiro security on/off in apache camel. You may alternately achieve this by including a choice in your route setup as shown below and injecting the on/off option as a header property while injecting the security token:

```
<route>
<from uri="bean:com.ngt.secured.ShiroSecurity?method=tokeninject(Exchange)"/>
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>${in.header.isSecured} == 'true'</simple>
        <policy ref="shiroPolicy">
            <to uri="bean:com.ngt.secured.transform?method=addrip(Exchange)"/>
             ...
             some process..
        </policy>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <to uri="bean:com.ngt.secured.transform?method=addrip(Exchange)"/>
         ...
         some process..
    </otherwise>
</choice>            
</route>

public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("SHIRO_SECURITY_TOKEN", encrypt());
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("isSecured", Boolean.FALSE);
    //exchange.getIn().setBody("Beatle Mania");
}
```